# Create point in intersections of two layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point, intersection, line

I have two layers. One of them is 'Road_line' and another one is 'forest_shape'.
I want to create a point layer that has points in intersection of that layers. I couldn't find any tools for it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try [Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000.htm) tool in the analyses toolbox if you are on ArcGIS. Set output to point.

Comment: According to ESRI documentation, when you set output to point, if the inputs are line or polygon, the output will be a multipoint feature class.  What if you want separate points which each inherit attributes from the intersecting features?