# Add the distance along the route for intersection points of polylines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, intersection, arcgis-10.5

I have two *sets* of polylines, illustrated in the screenshot (roads in purple and bridges in blue). I want to find the distance along the route for intersection point of each bridges from the starting point of the road and add it as a field to the bridge attribute table. Essentially, I want to add a stationing field in reference to start of the road to the bridges. See the screenshot below for clarification;

[image]

What I thought of doing is [creating a point feature with the intersections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/create-point-in-intersections-of-two-layers), then [finding the distance along the route for those points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277679/calculate-distance-to-points-along-line-in-arcmap), and later join the bridge and the created features to add the stationing in the bridges table. However that seems like a workaround to me. Is there a more straightforward method to do this?

Comment: Are you comfortable using Python for this?  I would extract the geometry object of the line, and then use the `measureOnLine(somePoint)` function to get the distance along the line of each intersection point.  You'd still have to calculate the intersection points first, but this is fairly straightforward.  See:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/polyline.htm